# The next step is to to do something, with two to's

Tags: grammar, verbs

I noticed that in some articles, there are sentences like "The next step is to to do something" with two to's. Is it legit or just a typo?

If it's legit, what's the grammar structure here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a typo, and as you say a (suprisingly) frequent one. Ignore the second *to*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typo.

Comment: Or you can ignore the first *to*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not a typo, and depending on the context, it might be a slangy way of saying 'to add something to a to-do list' by making a noun into a verb.